# Combining Laravel + Vue.js I got Error: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Pages/${name}' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site\resources\js''"

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I got this error in the terminal:

> "ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 5:11-37
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Pages/${name}' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\my-site\resources\js'
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error" and error in browser console "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>
> Target class [App\Http\HandleInertiaRequests] does not exist.'".

I have created the folder `/Pages/` in `/resources/js/` folder and put the file `Welcome.vue` with this code:

```js
<template>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

then I did this in `app.js`:

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'; 

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => require('./Pages/${name}'),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props)})
        .use(plugin)
        .mount(el)
    },
});
```

As I'm using vue3, I also did this in `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ])
    .version();
```

And, of course, I added the middleware in `Kernel.php`

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        HandleInertiaRequests::class
    ],
```

Please help me understand the problem and fix it. I'm new in laravel and vue.js and I need this for my end of studies project.

Answer (score 0):

Add resolve & alias in vite.config.js

eg:

```
 export default defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
     resolve: {
         alias: [
             {
                 find: '@',
                 replacement:'/resources/js/src/'
             },
             {
                 // this is required for the SCSS modules
                 find: /^~(.*)$/,
                 replacement: '$1',
             },
         ],
     }, 
     plugins: [
      vue(),
      laravel({
          input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
          refresh: true,
      }),
  ], });
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i couldn't find this file anywhere

Comment: You are using webpack then try , mix.vue()